# Data Visualisation

Tags: graph, data-visualization

**UPDATE:** I had posted this on UI.stackexchange also for views on different kinds od visualisation. I am posting this here for finding out the programming techniques and tools required to do so.

Let us have the following three sets of information

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Now I want to combine all of this data and show it all together. Telling it like a story. Giving inter-relations. Showing similarities in terms, concepts etc. to get the following (Note that in the diagram below, the colored relations may not be exact, they are merely indicative of a node of information)

[image]

**Situation:** I need to tell somebody the relation between two or more important things through the commonness of concepts, keywords, behaviours in those things.

One way that I figured out would be to use circles for concepts.
So that all concepts connected to thing A would be connected to it and all concept related to B would be connected to it. And the common concepts would be connected to both. That way 2 things can be easily compared.

**Problem:** To build such a graph/visualisation manually would be cumbersome. Especially to add, arrange, update and manipulate.

**Question:** Is there a good way to do it. Also, Is there a tool available for doing this?

I hope this make the question much more clear. :)

Comment: You might want to run this question by ui.stackexchange.

Comment: I guess I'll do that too. However I posted it here because the programming intensive nature of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to display the hierarchical data](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/953/how-to-display-the-hierarchical-data-closed) on **User Interface**

Answer (score 2):

Where does this data (the concepts, keywords, and relations between them etc...) come from? If it's in a database somewhere you could write soem code to generate a [graphiz](http://www.graphviz.org/) file then open it in a graphiz visualizer. There might be some tools out there that allow interactive editing of a graphiz graph, it looks like WebDot may and there are probably others.

Comment: The data is in excel sheets currently :\ But the dataset is not so large. maybe a hundred or so terms per thing and around a couple of dozen things.

Comment: If it's just CSV you could write code to process it line-by-line, OR you could load it to a database and then process to graphviz. If your spreadsheet has multiple worksheets, formulas, and macros, you might want to write the processing code in VBA. Going with code will be worth it in the long run if you expect your dataset to grow.

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php <- here's where all the good graphiz resources are!

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). I think there should be plenty of online and offline tools that can help making [these](http://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/index.html).
graphiz has been mentioned already, although that would be used more to show a flow of a system, or a treeview.
When you're talking about software development and want to display a design through diagrams, a complete diagram solution already exist as UML. And there are plenty of UMT tools that can help here. A commercial version is [Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html), which has some very nice features. You could probably use [Use Cases](http://www.altova.com/umodel/use-case-diagrams.html) as the most logical diagram type.
Also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram) for more info about use case diagrams. Reconsidering the image you've added, I do tend to consider it to be a usecase. Since UML is based on XML, it should be possible to transform your data through a stylesheet to UML, then use a random UML tool to display the diagrams.
To convert your data to XML, well... If it's in Excel then exporting it to XML should not be too difficult.
Why is your sample image an Use Case? Well, you have actors (Pinguin, Koala, Tulips) and you have actions. (well, kind of actions: Cause for concern, some kind of animal, linked to movie, bites your nose off...) And finally, there are associations between the actors and the actions connecting them all in some way. Thus Data`--(export)->`XML`--(Styleheet)->`UML`--(UML tool)->`Diagram.

Comment: Venn diagrams not exactly. keywords linked to a concept through lines like a network is what I have in mind.

Comment: I think the "circles" are just the node-shape (could have been squares or triangles maybe), and they are connected by edges, not overlapping areas, but I agree it's not 100% clear. Am I right, somewhat, or not at all?

Comment: Sure we're not talking about a kind of Use Cases here? Each use case would be a concept, which you would connect with lines.

Comment: Its more like the "two friends with similar like" thing. Or "courses with similar topics"...

Comment: I can visualize an use case in that example. :-) The friends would be associated to things, and two friends can be associated to the same thing. Things could be generalizations of other things, or just extend them. While it sounds a bit strange to use UML, it might give you the nicest results.

Answer (score 0):

[D3: Data-Driven Documents](http://d3js.org) JS library